# Encoding a hyperlink in CSV formatted file doesn't work

Tags: python, libreoffice

The problem is here;

```py
f'=HYPERLINK("http://{os.getenv("OPTION_HOST_IP")}:8000/test/opt?sec={final_list[1]}&st={summary_row[4]}&exp={summary_row[1]}&cp={final_list[6]}", "Daily")'
```

This just returns text in *LibreOffice*.

What should I do?

The other article told me to use double quotes, but that doesn't work for me either.

The cell in *LibreOffice* has this even though this is the correct format this is not an instant hyperlink. I still need to double click and then *LibreOffice* understood this is a hyperlink

```py
=HYPERLINK("http://IP/test/opt?sec=C&str=290.0&exp=2006-08-25&cp=C", "Daily")
```

Comment: To build a URL safely you can use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module. For this task you'll need two functions - [`urlunsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunsplit) *(to build a URL)* and [`urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) *(to build query string)*: `f'=HYPERLINK("{urlunsplit(("http", os.getenv("OPTION_HOST_IP) + ":8000", "/test/opt", urlencode({"sec": final_list[1], "st": summary_row[4], "exp": summary_row[1], "cp": final_list[6]}), ""))}", "Daily")'`

Comment: Thanks a lot @OlvinRoght will try and let you know, best regards

Comment: @OlvinRoght this is converting the expected link as always but again LibreOffice doesn't read it as hyperlink it shows this instead;


=HYPERLINK("http://IP/test/opt?sec=C&str=290.0&exp=2006-08-25&cp=C", "Daily")

Comment: I've just shown you the proper way to build an URL in python, that wasn't an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening your csv in Libre Office, in the text import pop up that shows up, you should check "Evaluate formulas" option.

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake. The problem is not there I will correct those mistakes now and you can see more clearly

Comment: I bonified my answer.

Comment: OH OK, that's great thanks a lot. One more question, do you know if I use openpyxl instead of CSV, will it auto import like a formula? @FrançoisFournier